# Generar un id unico en mi fichero bat

Tags: batch

Hola he hecho un pequeño bat para que me arranque una aplicacion con un log diferente ej.

```
Applicacion -many -workdir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\instance3\data"
```

Pero lo que quería hacer que el valor instance3 cada vez que lo arranco sea unico por tanto cada log será diferente.
Es posible generar un id unico ej.

```
Applicacion -many -workdir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"idunico"\data"
```

Como puedo llevar a cabo este cometido? o al menos como generarlo en mi bat para que cada vez que lo arranque sea diferente.

Puede ser numérico, letras o alfa numérico o combinacion de todos pero el id cada vez que arranque el bat debe ser diferente.

Comment: Te falta agregar a tu pregunta como sería el id, ¿sería numérico, letras o alfa numérico, que tipo de id?

Comment: puede ser combinacion de numeros o letras o alfa numero pero cada vez que se genere debe ser diferente. un id unico cada vez que arranque el bat. lo añadire como puede ser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es usar **%RANDOM%**, para generar un numero random entre 0 y 32767 y lo usarías de esta forma:

```
Applicacion -many -workdir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\%RANDOM%\data"
```